# i18next in nodes express only display the key and not the language string

Tags: express, internationalization, nodes, i18next

I try nodes express since a  few days
I have used some tutorials for using i18next
but don't find my fail.

I only get the key not der Languagestring.
Two whole day and I think i newer will see my fail.

This my project in Visual Studio 2022
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjwbi.png)

I will show my files :

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

// Internationalisation
const i18next = require('i18next');
const i18backend = require('i18next-fs-backend');
const i18middleware = require('i18next-http-middleware');

i18next
    .use(i18backend)
    .use(i18middleware.LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        backend: {
            loadPath: __dirname + '/resources/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
        },
        fallbackLng: 'de',
        preload: ['de']
    });

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const { response } = require('express');
const { Console } = require('console');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));                       // Middelware start
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(i18middleware.handle(i18next));                                 // Internationalisation

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

**my index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();



router.get('/imp', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('impressumpage',
        {
            title: "-" + req.t('impressum'),
            title2: 'Impressum',
            textDescript: 'Hier gehts um das Impressum und was man damit anfangen kann ',
            impress: 'Impressum',
            dataSafe: 'Datenschutzerkl\u00e4rung'
        });
});
```

**and my tranlation.json**
{
"appTitle": "VT usw.",
"dataprotec": "Datenschutzerklrung",
"impressum": "Impressum de"
}

I only get the key, why ?

I expect the language : here   -Impressum de